# TypeError: Prsone.__init__() missing 6 required positional argument: 'name,size,he0or0she,age,Language,new'

Tags: python

```
class Prsone():
  def __init__(self, name, size, he0or0she, age, Language) -> None:
    self.name = name
    self.size = size
    self.he0or0she = he0or0she
    self.age = age
    self.LGGE = Language
    

  def learning(self):
      x=input('میشه یک چیزی یادم بدی؟')
      f=open('yg.txt')
      f.write(x)
      f.close()
      print('ممنون')
```

`aly=Prsone(name='aly',size=2cm,he0or0she='AI',age='none',Language='fa-IR')`

`aly().learning()`

I want to make an artificial intelligence that executes a piece of code (learning) every time I call the `aly().learning()`function, but the error gives `NameError: name 'aly' is not defined`.

(i codeing with google colab)

i try it for delete the aly Variable ,but get the 'TypeError: Prsone.**init**() missing 6 required positional argument: 'name,size,he0or0she,age,Language,new''error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling aly which is an object like a method. So you'd need to remove the first brackets beside aly. So aly () becomes just aly. Secondly you can't pass the size like that, make it a string by wrapping it in quotes.  The code below should work as expected

```
 class Prsone():
  def __init__(self, name, size, he0or0she, age, Language) -> None:
    self.name = name
    self.size = size
    self.he0or0she = he0or0she
    self.age = age
    self.LGGE = Language
    

  def learning(self):
      x=input('میشه یک چیزی یادم بدی؟')
      f=open('yg.txt')
      f.write(x)
      f.close()
      print('ممنون')
aly=Prsone(name='aly',size='2cm',he0or0she='AI',age='none',Language='fa-IR')
aly.learning()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the method by `aly().learning()`, but call it by `aly.learning()`, since you've initialized `aly`, which is the instance of `Prsone`.

`classname` + `()` means you are constructing an new object by calling `classname.__init__()`.